# android: user preference data location in windows

Tags: android, preferences

I'm using Windows to develop android apps and want to know where user preference data is located. It says at /data/data/package/...., but where can I actually see the preference file? Via eclipse or command line tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using Windows to develop android
>   apps and want to know where user
>   preference data is located.

Those two concepts are not related.

> It says at /data/data/package/....,
>   but where can I actually see the
>   preference file?

Use DDMS's File Manager (either from standalone DDMS or Eclipse), or use `adb pull` from the command line to download the file to your Windows PC.

Comment: Got it. Wasn't aware of DDMS perspective.